# Create VBA to autoassign type

Tags: vba, excel

I am a beginner in VBA programming.

[image: Screenshot]

**Description**: The left table is the 'reference table'

**Objective**: Fill up the 'Type' col of right table using macro

**How**: Write a macro that go through the 'reference table' comparing col E (Descript) with keyword. If the cell in col E contain a specific key word, col F will automatically be assigned a category

P.S: What are the recommended websites that provide tutorial? Something like codecademy

So still stuck at correctly referencing table:
[image]

Comment: Hi @Shawn, that's a very clearly worded question, but you'll get a much more favourable response from the community if you show that you've already attempted to solve the problem yourself, then got stuck somewhere and need help going further. This isn't really the right place to look for tutorials - I would recommend MrExcel as a starting point, and the in-built help function of Excel itself. In this case, you'll want to use the InStr() function, and step through your reference table row by row.

Comment: @Eddy I have learned some of the basics such as looping and referencing. The thing is it doesn't seems right when I try to join them together. Either syntax error or it doesn't make sense. That said, I am still working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for editing your answer to include the code. Next time please copy/paste it, rather than using an image, so that we don't have to type it all out ourselves if we need to test what you've written! I can see where you're at now, and I feel this will work you for. Basically, you need to cycle through the rows rather than the columns.

Rather than using a subroutine, I think a function will work better for you. That way you can embed it in your table, rather than having to run a subroutine each time.

```
Function getCategory(strInput As String)
  Dim tbl As ListObject
  Dim x As Long

  Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
  For x = 1 To tbl.ListRows.Count
    If InStr(strInput, tbl.ListRows(x).Range(x, 1)) Then
        getCategory = tbl.ListRows(x).Range(x, 2)
        Exit Function
    End If
  Next x
End Function
```

Then you can simply enter the formula in column F, e.g. in F2 enter
=getCategory(E2)
and copy/paste down for each row in your table.

Comment: Thanks! I will go break this down to understand what this means. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Shawn I'm happy to hear my answer was useful - I would appreciate it you "accept" the answer.